# How can I see, on a Windows 2008 and/or 2003 a list with all the domain controllers in the current domain?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows

I have a Win 2008 as primary domain controller and a Win 2003 as secondary domain controller. Apparently, the lately added W2003 automagically and nicely synchronized all users and groups and everything look OK.

However, I am curious, is there a place in the Server Manager where I can see a list with all the other domain controllers, both on 2008 and/or 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, firstly there is no such thing as a primary and secondary domain controller in Active Directory, it is a multi-master setup and all controllers are equal. Some will hold FSMO roles that others won't, but that is it.

In answer to your question, if you look in Active directory users and computers and go into the "Domain Controllers" folder, you will see all domain controllers in your domain listed. You can view what OS is installed on them by double clicking on them and going to the operating system tab.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ... I was looking at that windows for 15 minutes and didn't observe the "Domain Controllers" entry ... LOL.

Comment: Just to be clear, domain controllers go in here by default but on an existing network someone could have moved them to elsewhere in the AD tree.

Comment: OK, I understand, I was just curious to see that my 2 domain servers know about each other.

Comment: Something like "netdom query dc" from a command prompt will give you an authoritative list regardless of what OU the computer accounts are in.

Answer (score 2):

if you expand active directory tree you can look for a folder called domain controllers